# Is asking for precedent cases on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Can I ask "has there ever been a legal case where X" (with appropriate specifics of course) here?

If it matters, the purpose wouldn't be to get legal advice for a legal case I'm involved in, it's more a research topic for some background info in a letter to my city's council that I'm trying to compose. I haven't had any luck finding info on my own, and my lawyer friends all say that it's difficult to research this type of thing.

I read the [legal-research](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-research) tag description (which I saw in [this somewhat related meta question](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1671/are-questions-asking-for-help-in-how-to-search-for-past-cases-on-topic)), and my interpretation is that it *is* on topic, except... it seems like it's potentially asking for a lot i.e. something an investigator might do for a fee. So I'm not really sure how well such a question would be received.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is asking for precedent cases on topic? Can I ask "has there ever been a legal case where X" (with appropriate specifics of course) here?

Yes. That pertains to "*court decisions*" as well as "*historical legal applications*", two items listed on [What topics can I ask about here](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

> If it matters, the purpose wouldn't be to get legal advice for a legal case I'm involved in, it's more a research topic for some background info in a letter to my city's council that I'm trying to compose.

In line with the second paragraph in a [recent answer](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1680/18505), questions are on topic or off-topic regardless of the ultimate reason for your inquiry.

On the one hand, disclosing the purpose you have in mind could prompt knowledgeable, good faith contributors that to make you aware of caveats or substleties you might be missing and need to know.

On the other hand, other users are fond of voting to close posts, and your candor will prompt them to censor yours. They will allege that your intended use of the information amounts to request for legal advice. The number of downvotes in the linked answer is *a* (i.e., not the only) reflection of that.

> it seems like it's potentially asking for a lot i.e. something an investigator might do for a fee.

A contributor's ability and willingness to find and/or explain legal sources for free has nothing to do with whether a question is on topic.